# Getting data for two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js, 2-way-object-databinding

Why I don't have access to data from method defined in onclick method?

```
onclick: function(d, i) {
  $scope.country = d.name;
  console.log($scope.country);
}
```

I want to get the name from the object and show in HTML `<h1>Clicked: {{country}}</h1>` 
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OhhaH5LIldTTagwZmnCk?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

country-item directive has an isolated scope defined inside it.
So, you need to pass it the country in the html:

```
<country-item country="country"></country-item>
```

If you need to add the same behavior when clicking on the Chart bars, you must add $scope.$apply() in the onClick callback:

```
onclick: function(d, i) {
    $scope.country = d.name;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

The digest cycle has finished and you need to inform Angular that something has changed.

Comment: I already tried, it doesn't work :/ http://plnkr.co/edit/OhhaH5LIldTTagwZmnCk?p=preview

Comment: I think he wants to show country of Bar chart data onclick

Comment: It works on records in table, but doesn't when clicked bar on the chart.